# Editing HTML Code using Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, html-parsing, vba

I am in need of editing html code using VBA. I actually got this working as far as editing values of text boxes. My problem is that when I simulate clicking the "submit" button there are new tables that come up. The web address stays the same but now there is new html code generated for the tables. I am trying to read data from these tables but it seems as if they don't exist when I try and query them. So I am guessing that I need to update or refresh the IE html code after I press the "submit" button. I can not seem to figure out how to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code so far:

```
Sub ImportStackOverflowData()

Dim SearchFor As IHTMLElement
Dim RowNumber As Long
RowNumber = 4

'to refer to the running copy of Internet Explorer
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
'to refer to the HTML document returned
Dim html As HTMLDocument
'open Internet Explorer in memory, and go to website
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "http://google.com"
'Wait until IE is done loading page
Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to TRSDataBase ..."
DoEvents
Loop

Set html = ie.Document
Application.StatusBar = ""

'clear old data out and put titles in
Cells.Clear

Set SearchFor = html.getElementById("ddl_process")

'if this is the tag containing the question details, process it
If SearchFor.ID = "ddl_process" Then

'Replace the value of dl-process with copperhead name
Call SearchFor.setAttribute("value", "CPHB_FAT")
Cells(RowNumber, 1).Value = "Successfully replaced ddl_process to : " &     
SearchFor.getAttribute("value")

'go on to next row of worksheet
RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
End If

Set SearchFor = html.getElementById("txt_startdate")
If SearchFor.ID = "txt_startdate" Then

'Replace the value of dl-process with copperhead name
Call SearchFor.setAttribute("value", "07-07-17")
Cells(RowNumber, 1).Value = "Successfully replaced startdate to : " &     
SearchFor.getAttribute("value")

'go on to next row of worksheet
RowNumber = RowNumber + 1

End If

Set SearchFor = html.getElementById("txt_enddate")
If SearchFor.ID = "txt_enddate" Then

'Replace the value of dl-process with copperhead name
Call SearchFor.setAttribute("value", "07-14-17")
Cells(RowNumber, 1).Value = "Successfully replaced enddate to : " &             
SearchFor.getAttribute("value")

'go on to next row of worksheet
RowNumber = RowNumber + 1

End If
'find view button and click it
Set SearchFor = html.getElementById("btn_header")
If SearchFor.ID = "btn_header" Then
    SearchFor.Click
    Cells(RowNumber, 1).Value = "The View Button has been clicked."
    'go on to next row of worksheet
    RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
End If


'Now get data from table after it loads
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:20"))  
 Set html = ie.Document   <----------This is where i am trying to update or refresh my code after it loads with the new tables

Debug.Print ie.Document.body.innerHTML
Range("L5").Value = ie.Document.getElementsByTag("table")
(1).Rows(1).Cells(2).innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting a new pointer to the window. Sometimes that does the trick.

```
Public Function FindWindow(SearchBy As String, SearchCriteria As String) As Object
    Dim Window As Object

    For Each Window In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        If SearchBy = "URL" And Window.LocationURL Like "*" & SearchCriteria & "*" Then
            Set FindWindow = Window
            Exit Function
        ElseIf SearchBy = "Name" And Window.LocationName Like "*" & SearchCriteria & "*" Then
            Set FindWindow = Window
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    Set FindWindow = Nothing
End Function

Sub getNewPointer()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer

    ie.Navigate "www.google.com"

    'Wait for the page to load and do actions etc
    'Your code here
    '
    '

    'Clear the IE reference
    Set ie = Nothing

    'get a new pointer to the window of interest
    'Keep in mind it finds the first matching Window based on your criteria!
    Set ie = FindWindow("URL", "www.google.ca")

    'Try getting the property you want
    Debug.Print
End Sub
```

Comment: Im a little confused by how your going about this. Could you incorporate it into my code for me. I think you have the right idea I just cant combine your code with mine. Thanks

Comment: I think i might have merged it correctly but it is still not working.

Comment: Wouldnt this work?  Dim ie2 As InternetExplorer

       Set ie2 = Nothing

       Set ie2 = FindWindow("URL", "www.google.com")

       Set html = ie2.Document

Comment: You want to call the FindWindow function to get a new pointer after you press submit and the other tables load. Updating this reference should update the IE object's properties.